# Using variable generated from the Django view in the Javascript in Django template?

Tags: javascript, python, django

This variable below stores the processing in variable name **proc**:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['sshpass', '-p', password, 'rsync', '-avz', '--info=progress2', source12, destination], 
                                    stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

I am a form in a Django template. Whenever the user presses the button **Submit** I want to use the variable proc and show the processing. I tried using the variable proc in Django template Javascript like this:

```
function popUp() {
    var a = "{{proc}}"
    document.write(a)
}
</script>
```

But it shows only the empty page. I have tested variable directly calling inside the html body tag it works fine but doesn't work with javascript. What I am doing wrong?

I am calling the **popUp** function like this in the Django template like this:

```
<form name="form1" action="/sync/" method="post" onsubmit="popUp()">
```

And, I am passing the variable **proc** in the Django template like this:

```
return render_to_response('synced.html', {'final_result':final_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
return render_to_response('thanks.html', {'proc':proc}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**Edit:**
For the checking, instead of passing the variable into thanks.html I passed the variable **proc** into **synced.html** and used in template like this:

```
<th>Files in the server:</th>
</tr>
<td>{{ proc }}</td>
<tr>
```

and my output is:

```
receiving incremental file list 0 0% 0.00kB/s 0:00:00 (xfr#0, to-chk=0/1) sent 20 bytes received 56 bytes 6.08 bytes/sec total size is 8,640 speedup is 113.68
```

Comment: Are you calling the `popUp` function?

Comment: I am calling the popUp function.

Comment: Well I'm not sure why it's a _blank_ page, but using `document.write` after the page has been rendered is not good - it will overwrite the page with anything you specify...in your case `a`. So that means `a` is empty for some reason. Also, since you are submitting a form, the page will be cleared since the request is sent to the browser for "/sync/" and the response could be filling the page with nothing for some reason

Comment: It's overriding the page if I use static string like this document.write("Processing..")

Comment: Instead of `document.write`, try `alert`. Does that alert any value?

Comment: It alerts the empty box that means the value of variable proc is not passed.

Comment: Hmm okay. And what's the code you use in the `body` that works? Can you provide that?

Comment: Ok. I will update my question.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure. Something random I just noticed...why do you have `return render_to_response('synced.html', 'thanks.html',` ? Two strings as parameters?

Comment: I returned the variable final_list which I need in the synced.html and I have another variable returned proc returned for thanks.html and use in JavaScript.

Comment: Right, but why are you providing 2 template files? `render_to_response` has 3 parameters that you would be using - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response - so I'm not sure why you passing both "synced.html" and "thanks.html" to the same method. I don't think I understand your django logic...

Comment: My logic was wrong. I have now used to render_to_response but still no luck. See my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest what you are doing is not wrong but there are better ways & technologies have been engineered to solve this usecase of yours. Some of the things you can try -

1. AJAX Polling - Use a client-side timer, you constantly poll the server about it's status.
2. COMET - comet is a PUSH technology. As HTTP is a pull technology you can have a persistent connection between server & client and have server PUSH the progress to you.

Not the answer you were looking for but hopefully this helps...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not much familiar with AJAX and COMET. I want my problem to be solved quick using the simple javascript.

Comment: `comet` might be complex but ajax is javascript predominantly and its easy.